# How can I change mouse hover behavior for hyperlinks in a notebook?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, hyperlink

When I create a `Hyperlink` to a *Youtube* video in a text cell the link is colored blue like it would be in a browser.  However, the mouse cursor does not change when it hovers over a link.

This causes my students to think that the link doesn't work or isn't really a link. To them it just looks like I have blue colored text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is in a `TextCell`, you can do this:

- create an inline cell, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>
- put there your link with: `MouseAppearance[Hyperlink["test", "testlink"], "LinkHand"]`
- `Evaluate In Place` with `Evaluate` menu or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>.

and it should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I use the GUI to insert link to a text by highlighting text -> Toolbar: `Insert -> hyperlink`. When I hover the mouse over the blue text it does change from `I` to arrow.

[image: snapshot]

Then I use the  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>  +  <kbd>E</kbd>  to reveal the expression of cell:

```
Cell[RawData["\<\
Cell[TextData[{
 ButtonBox[\"test\",
  BaseStyle->\"Hyperlink\",
  ButtonData->{
URL[\"http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37513/how-\
can-i-change-mouse-hover-\\
behavior-for-hyperlinks-in-a-notebook\"], None},
  ButtonNote->
   \"http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37513/how-can-i-\
change-mouse-hover-behavior-\\
for-hyperlinks-in-a-notebook\"],
 \" test2\"
}], \"Text\",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.594011671826529*^9, 3.594011727217702*^9}}]\
\>"], "Text",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.594011671826529*^9, 3.594011727217702*^9}}]
```

As long as the ButtonBox is present, you should be able to see the change of the cursor when hovering.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Is there a property that I can set in my stylesheet to get this behavior by default?

Comment: If you insert from the GUI, you will get this behavior by default and I think this is independent from stylesheet.

Comment: I don't get it when I insert using the GUI.

Comment: If you use the show expression key bind, you do not see:`TextData`or `ButtonBox` ?