# Apply a style to a selected structure

Tags: evaluation, formatting, input

If I type out, in my notes, a series of transformations, I often like to convert the very last step to a `Framed` equation:

[image]

I'm currently doing this by:

1. selecting the last expression,
2. copying it,
3. pasting it in a new field,
4. adding `Framed[ … ]` and evaluating,
5. copying the result,
6. pasting it back in the original field.

Is there a hotkey or quick way for me to apply a transformation *to a selection*, replacing it with the result? (Or something like that.)

Thanks!

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Enter is the keyboard shortcut for "evaluate in place", which you press after highlighting an expression; this should ease your task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut for "evaluate in place", which you press after highlighting an expression; this should ease your task. – J. M.♦ 2 mins ago

[image]

Notice I used `Defer`, it holds its arguments and is stripped when boxes are created. Exactly what we need keep e.g. `1 + 1` in this form.

Related:

[How can I change mouse hover behavior for hyperlinks in a notebook?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37513/5478)

Comment: Didn't have a computer, so thanks for following through!

Comment: This is excellent, especially with the `.gif`! Truly concise, helpful answer. <3

Answer (score 2):

You could also use InputAliases. For example:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases] = {
    "fr" -> FrameBox[
        "\[SelectionPlaceholder]",
        BaselinePosition->Baseline,
        Background->LightGray
    ],
    ParentList
};
```

Here is a short animation using the alias:

[image]

**Addendum**

The nice thing about this approach compared to the accepted answer is that the added frame is transparent to the evaluation process. Here's an animation comparing the two approaches:

[image]

**Explanation**

One further comment. The difference between the two cases is that the evaluate in place approach used [`Framed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Framed), which by default has the option `StripOnInput->False`. Using:

```
10 == Framed[Defer[11-1], StripOnInput->True]
```

would produce a wrapper that is transparent to evaluation